# Cannot convert return expression of type '(AnyPublisher<DemoObject, Never>, APIError)' to return type 'AnyPublisher<DemoObject, APIError>'

Tags: swift

```
func testData()->AnyPublisher<DemoObject, APIError> {

    var data = DummyData().decodeClaimDetails()!
    
    return (Just(data).eraseToAnyPublisher(),
            APIError.httpError(200))
    
}
```

I got this error.
Cannot convert return expression of type '(AnyPublisher<DemoObject, Never>, APIError)' to return type 'AnyPublisher<DemoObject, APIError>'

How can I return a type that is AnyPublisher<DemoObject, APIError>?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want

```
func testData()->AnyPublisher<DemoObject, APIError> {
    let d: DemoObject = // ...
    return Just<DemoObject>(d)
        .setFailureType(to: APIError.self) // <--
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```